# How to filter Google Analytics data from multiple accounts in Tableau dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, tableau-api

If you pull data from from multiple Google Analytics accounts, how do you filter data to be able to see information from just one of those accounts in a dashboard?

For example, if there are three accounts A, B, and C, and the data is shown as such in the dashboard:

```
  A B C
X 3 4 5
Y 2 1 6
```

How can I apply a filter so I only see A or B or C. I think there's a trivial way to do this, but it's eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your accounts are configured to different domains you can use the dimension 'Hostname' and apply this as a filter, you'll then be able to select the appropriate profiles for your workbook.

Ben

Comment: Great idea, didn't work for me, but did give me the idea to look for unique fields that I could filter by, thanks.